use reverse rank in a fby statement
How does one accomplish a reverse rank in an fby?
In the below, how would we select the two largest values of col2 by date?
q)dt: 2024.05.13 2024.05.17 2024.05.16 2024.05.17 2024.05.14 2024.05.13 2024.05.16 2024.05.16 2024.05.15 2024.05.16 2024.05.16 2024.05.14 2024.05.13 2024.05.15 2024.05.16 2024.05.14 2024.05.13 2024.05.14

q)col1: 0 13 45 19 30 72 54 4 55 40 46 62 5 18 88 92 20 27

q)col2: 9107 9325 3813 9198 9227 8418 7868 3945 9840 1227 5613 5591 8140 9703 1225 8801 5940 9433

q)t: ([] date: dt; col1:col1; col2:col2)

q)t
date       col1 col2
--------------------
2024.05.13 0    9107
2024.05.17 13   9325
2024.05.16 45   3813
2024.05.17 19   9198
2024.05.14 30   9227
2024.05.13 72   8418
2024.05.16 54   7868
2024.05.16 4    3945
2024.05.15 55   9840
2024.05.16 40   1227
2024.05.16 46   5613
2024.05.14 62   5591
2024.05.13 5    8140
2024.05.15 18   9703
2024.05.16 88   1225
2024.05.14 92   8801
2024.05.13 20   5940
2024.05.14 27   9433

This attempt didn't work. The values for some of the dates are wrong.
q)gt: select from t where 2>(idesc;col2) fby date

q)`date`col2 xdesc gt
date       col1 col2
--------------------
2024.05.17 13   9325
2024.05.17 19   9198
2024.05.16 45   3813
2024.05.16 40   1227
2024.05.15 55   9840
2024.05.15 18   9703
2024.05.14 27   9433
2024.05.14 62   5591
2024.05.13 0    9107
2024.05.13 72   8418


q)`date`col2 xdesc t
date       col1 col2
--------------------
2024.05.17 13   9325
2024.05.17 19   9198
2024.05.16 54   7868
2024.05.16 46   5613
2024.05.16 4    3945
2024.05.16 45   3813
2024.05.16 40   1227
2024.05.16 88   1225
2024.05.15 55   9840
2024.05.15 18   9703
2024.05.14 27   9433
2024.05.14 30   9227
2024.05.14 92   8801
2024.05.14 62   5591
2024.05.13 0    9107
2024.05.13 72   8418
2024.05.13 5    8140
2024.05.13 20   5940



(1) Why didn't the original fby work?
(2) What does work to accomplish the reverse rank?

idesc is returning indices needed to sort a list in descending order. The position of 0 index will not necessarily point to the largest value.
q)exec col2 from t where date=2024.05.16
3813 7868 3945 1227 5613 1225
q)idesc exec col2 from t where date=2024.05.16
1 4 2 0 3 5
q)select from t where date=2024.05.16,0=idesc col2
date       col1 col2
--------------------
2024.05.16 40   1227
q)select from t where date=2024.05.16,col2=max col2
date       col1 col2
--------------------
2024.05.16 54   7868

To get the largest col2 value by date you can use
q)select from t where col2=(max;col2)fby date
date       col1 col2
--------------------
2024.05.13 0    9107
2024.05.17 13   9325
2024.05.16 54   7868
2024.05.15 55   9840
2024.05.14 27   9433


You could also do:
q)select from t where({x in 2#desc x};col2)fby date
date       col1 col2
--------------------
2024.05.13 0    9107
2024.05.17 13   9325
2024.05.17 19   9198
2024.05.14 30   9227
2024.05.13 72   8418
2024.05.16 54   7868
2024.05.15 55   9840
2024.05.16 46   5613
2024.05.15 18   9703
2024.05.14 27   9433

select from t where({x in -2#asc x};col2)fby date


If you only need the date and col2 values, you can use a by clause:
q)select 2#desc col2 by date from t
date      | col2
----------| ---------
2024.05.13| 9107 8418
2024.05.14| 9433 9227
2024.05.15| 9840 9703
2024.05.16| 7868 5613
2024.05.17| 9325 9198

You can use ungroup to flatten:
q)ungroup select 2#desc col2 by date from t
date       col2
---------------
2024.05.13 9107
2024.05.13 8418
2024.05.14 9433
2024.05.14 9227
2024.05.15 9840
2024.05.15 9703
2024.05.16 7868
2024.05.16 5613
2024.05.17 9325
2024.05.17 9198

If you need all of the columns, then you can use fby. A repeated application of idesc is reverse rank:
q)select from t where 2>(idesc/[2;];col2)fby date
date       col1 col2
--------------------
2024.05.17 13   9325
2024.05.17 19   9198
2024.05.14 30   9227
2024.05.16 54   7868
2024.05.15 55   9840
2024.05.16 46   5613
2024.05.13 5    8140
2024.05.15 18   9703
2024.05.13 20   5940
2024.05.14 27   9433


in the fby answer, isn't the output for 2024.05.13 incorrect?

iasc idesc is reverse rank. You have to iasc to get back in order of the original list.
idesc idesc gives something else.

got this to work:
q)`date`col2 xdesc select from t where 2>({iasc idesc x}; col2) fby date
date       col1 col2
--------------------
2024.05.17 13   9325
2024.05.17 19   9198
2024.05.16 54   7868
2024.05.16 46   5613
2024.05.15 55   9840
2024.05.15 18   9703
2024.05.14 27   9433
2024.05.14 30   9227
2024.05.13 0    9107
2024.05.13 72   8418

